# Animate.js: How to use properly target on React.js element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-animate

I would like to use animate.js in my react.js app. Targeting a JSX element by *useRef* and *useEffect* doesn't work at all. I'm sure I'm still missing something.

Note: this is only an example! I only would like know how to use target on React.js elements.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import anime from "animejs/lib/anime.es.js";

const Sent = (props) => {

    const lettersRef = useRef(null);
    const MlRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {


    anime.timeline({ loop: true })
    .add({
      targets: lettersRef.current, //This is probably wrong. 
      translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
    })
    .add({
      targets: MlRef.current, //This is also probably wrong
      opacity: 0,
    });
},[]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.sentContainer}>
      <h2 class='Ml6' ref={MlRef}>
        <span class='Text_wrapper'>
          <span class='Letters' ref={lettersRef} > Some text </span>
        </span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is you're trying to animate an inline element, a span. Your `useRef` code is fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-platform-ngbdq?file=/src/Sent.js

Comment: It works! thank you for your time!